# Cannot use ListBox values in MS Access 2007 to pass to query

Tags: ms-access, vba

Good morning,

I am helping to develop an interface via a Form in MS Access. We have a list box with various user values and the user should be able to select multiple values in the ListBox and then press the button to execute a query, returning only the rows whose Car Name is what was selected.

UPDATE - thanks to some great feedback on this forum, the primary issue was resolved. My secondary issue is now not being able to execute the query. When I try, I get the error that the query cannot be executed.

My code (as event procedure) for the button is:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub btnSearchCars_Click()
    MsgBox "Starting Sub"
    Call QueryCars.myQuery
    MsgBox "Ending Sub"
End Sub
```

Then, my QueryCars module looks like this:

```
Sub myQuery()
    Dim strWhere As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim varItem As Variant

    For Each varItem in Forms!FormSelect!listCarID.SelectedItems
        strWhere = strWhere & "'" & Forms!FormSelect!listCarID.ItemData(varItem) & "',"
    Next
```

strWhere = Left(strWhere, Len(strWhere) -1)

```
    strSQL = "SELECT tblBig.* FROM tblCars INNER JOIN tblBig ON tblCars.Car_ID = tblBig.Car_ID WHERE tblCars.Car_ID IN (" & strWhere & ");"
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

End Sub
```

My error is an "A RunSQL requires an argument of an SQL statement" error on the line.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help. All I am trying to do is take the values from the list box the user selects and use them as WHERE criteria in my query. I have searched various SO and Access forums all morning and have not found anything to help.

Thank you. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: strWhere seems not well constructed, 1st you have twice the items added, 2nd you have a , at the end that need to be removed.

Comment: @VincentG thank you for the feedback. I made those changes but am still getting the same error.

Comment: The`myForm` declaration is wrong. It should be `As Access.Form` By using `Option Explicit` at the top of each module, you should be able to pick those errors at compile time..

Comment: Hi @KostasK. thank you for your response. Unfortunately, that did not fix my error, though I have adjusted the code.

Comment: Try to reference the ListBox control directly. `For Each varItem In FormName!listCarID.ItemsSelected`

Comment: Hi @KostasK. That is seemingly making things better. Thank you so much!

But now, I have a problem where I am getting an error saying "Cannot Execute Select Query".

Comment: You still have the , in excess at the end of strWhere

Comment: Hi @VincentG. I need that, don't I? Additionally, I have added an additional function to remove the trailing ',' that is not reflected here. I am primary concerned with the query not executing.

Comment: How can we know that you "have added an additional function to remove the trailing ','" if you don't tell us?

Comment: @VincentG, thanks for your feedback. I will add that in, but it is not relevant to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the perfect answer I was hoping to give you - but can't figure out how to use parameter queries in an `IN` command.

I'll assume that your listbox contains two columns of data and the `CarID` values are in the first column.

The main function is called `ProcessQuery` and accepts a reference to the listbox as an argument:
`Public Sub ProcessQuery(myList As ListBox)`

You can then call your code from the event on the listbox and pass it the listbox reference.

```
Private Sub btnSearchCars_Click()
    ProcessQuery Me.listCarID
End Sub
```

The `ProcessQuery` procedure then looks at the first column to get the index numbers, constructs the SQL, opens the resulting recordset and pulls the info from each record.

```
Public Sub ProcessQuery(myList As ListBox)

    Dim vItem As Variant
    Dim IDList As String
    Dim qdf As dao.QueryDef
    Dim rst As dao.Recordset

    For Each vItem In myList.ItemsSelected
        'Column 0 is first column in listbox.
        IDList = IDList & "'" & myList.Column(0, vItem) & "',"
    Next vItem
    'Removes the final ,
    IDList = Left(IDList, Len(IDList) - 1)

    'Create a temporary query definition & open the recordset.
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", _
        "SELECT tblBig.* FROM tblCars INNER JOIN tblBig ON tblCars.Car_ID = tblBig.Car_ID WHERE tblCars.Car_ID IN (" & IDList & ")")
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset

    'Move through the recordset and output the first two fields from each record
    'to the Immediate window.
    With rst
        If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
            .MoveFirst
            Do While Not .EOF
                Debug.Print .Fields(0) & " - " & .Fields(1)
                .MoveNext
            Loop
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

To display the query result as a datasheet you could use the following, but I'd prefer to use a stored query with a parameter for the `IN`.  I'll try and figure that bit out.

```
Public Sub ProcessQuery(myList As ListBox)

    Dim vItem As Variant
    Dim IDList As String
    Dim qdf As dao.QueryDef
    Dim rst As dao.Recordset

    For Each vItem In myList.ItemsSelected
        'Column 0 is first column in listbox.
        IDList = IDList & "'" & myList.Column(0, vItem) & "',"
    Next vItem
    'Removes the final ,
    IDList = Left(IDList, Len(IDList) - 1)

    'Create a temporary query definition & open the recordset.
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("TempQDF", _
        "SELECT tblBig.* FROM tblCars INNER JOIN tblBig ON tblCars.Car_ID = tblBig.Car_ID WHERE tblCars.Car_ID IN (" & IDList & ")")

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "TempQDF", acViewNormal

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Darren Bartrup-Cook, thank you so much for your reply! I just went ahead and spent the last 30 minutes implementing your idea, as well as trying to learn what you were doing and Googling terms I was unfamiliar with.

I do have one problem. It runs great with no errors, but, nothing happens...meaning no records return anywhere. I have added in some MsgBoxs to show that the function runs, which it does, but nothing actually populates. Do you have any advice?

Comment: A few things to check - 1.  step through the code using `F8`.  Does it execute the code within the `If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then` block - if not then it's a good sign the query hasn't returned anything.  2.  With the code paused after `IDList = Left(IDList, Len(IDList) - 1)` open the Immediate window (`Ctrl+G` to open in the VBE) and enter `?"SELECT tblBig.* FROM tblCars INNER JOIN tblBig ON tblCars.Car_ID = tblBig.Car_ID WHERE tblCars.Car_ID IN (" & IDList & ")"`.  Create a query using the SQL and see if it returns anything.

Comment: 3.  Open the Locals window and keep an eye on the variables as you step through the code - is `IDList` getting populated with the correct values?

Comment: Hi @Darren Batrup-Cook. Thanks a lot for your help. Unfortunately I cannot step through the code. Pressing F8 does nothing, and when I click "Run -> Step Into", Access prompts me to look for a macro and this is saved as a Module. Would you advise I create a formal macro?

Comment: Ah, yes.... forgot that you wouldn't be able to step through like that.  Put a break point on the `ProcessQuery Me.listCarID` line in your click event (click on the border to the left of the line and it should highlight the row with a dot in the border).  Open your form and press the button.  Your code will stop on the break point and then you can step through with F8.

Comment: Hi @Darren Bartrup-Cook. Again, thanks a lot for being so patient with me. I feel like I've been living on SO and UtterAccess trying to configure this thing.

I stepped through the code and the IDList variable fills out appropriately, the If Not Then block is looped through appropriately as well. 

I also took your advice and copied the SQL out of the VBE, and when I do, it runs perfectly. (FYI - it is in quotes in the VBE, and I needed to remove the quotes...should it be in the VBE EXACTLY how it is run?)

Comment: After you've entered it in the Immediate window and hit enter you should be able to copy the resulting SQL straight into a query and run it - within the code and the bit you type into the immediate window will require the quotes.  If it reaches the `.MoveFirst` line then there are records being returned.  Once the execution reaches this point hover the cursor over `.Fields(0)` - does it show a value in the tooltip?  Try `rst.MoveLast` and `?rst.RecordCount` in the Immediate window - does it return a value greater than 0?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173886/discussion-between-bm0r3son-and-darren-bartrup-cook).

Comment: Was going to say on my last comment - unfortunately I can't _because of its content categorization: "Chat (IM)/SMS;Technology/Internet"_  (or so my PC tells me).

Comment: Totally OK. I just appreciate your help. I do want to let you know that the .Fields line DOES show a value, and also both of the other items do return values > 0.

Comment: It's working then - `.Fields(0)` is just the first field return by your query on whichever record it's currently on.  You can use `.Fields("FieldName")` for specific fields. So I guess the next part is - what do you want to do with the data once you have it?  One suggestion would be the answer I gave here:  [control what spreadsheet a query is exported to in msaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50858307/control-what-spreadsheet-a-query-is-exported-to-in-msaccess/50879316#50879316)

Comment: I think my problem is that nothing opens up. Ideally, I just want to display the data. It doesn't need to be in any certain format, I just need it to display properly. We have a large configuration database of vehicles and their make / model, which type of oil they use, brakes, etc. When someone selects a list of cars, I want all of that information to appear. So just returning the records would be great. The problem is, nothing actually appears in Access when it runs.

Comment: I've added some code to display the results in a datasheet - not the answer I was hoping to give you though, but having trouble figuring out the syntax for passing an `IN` list from a parameter.

Comment: Hi @Darren Bartrup-Cook. That seems to work just perfectly. I really can't thank you enough for all of your help. I appreciate your patience and willing to teach me a few things; I definitely feel more comfortable now.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first taking a look at the actual WHERE clause being generated...keep a separate string variable to store it, and then dump it to the Immediate Window when it's generated.

I would also suggest creating a separate function to return values selected in a list box as an array. Something like:

```
Public Function getListBoxSelection(ctl As Access.ListBox) As Variant
   Dim arr() As Variant
   Dim varItem As Variant, i As Long

   If ctl.ItemsSelected.Count > 0 Then
      ReDim arr(0 To ctl.ItemsSelected.Count - 1)
      i = 0

      For Each varItem In ctl.ItemsSelected
         arr(i) = ctl.ItemData(varItem)
         i = i + 1
      Next varItem

   End If

   getListBoxSelection = arr
End Function
```

Then, you would call it in SQL generation. Something like

```
whereClause = join(getListBoxSelection(me.listCarID), " AND ")
debug.Print whereClause

qdf.SQL = _
    "select tblBig.* " & _
    "from tblCars " & _
    "inner join tblBig on tblCars.Cat_ID = tblBig.Car_ID " & _
    "where tblCars.Card_ID in (" & whereClause & ")"
```

Comment: Hey @Zack. I can go ahead and make these changes. Thanks for suggesting them. My current problem is, even when I run the Debug.Print OR run the DoCmd.OpenQuery, nothing actually pops up or happens...despite me not getting any errors.